# How to remove patterns and whitespaces from a scraped data?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, strip-tags

I have scraped data but having difficulty in removing the tags and white spaces such that each string word can iterable then added as a pair to a key

I converted the result to string, used the map function and join, then removed line spaces using regular expression, the result still had some tags but can't iterate the string since it now a string even while I tried converting from string back to list.

```
datetime_end_list = []
datetime = soup.find_all(class_="cloture-line")
for dt in datetime:
      df_text = dt.getText()
      datetime_end_list.append(df_text)
print(datetime_end_list)
'\r\n                                            17/04/202311:00\r\n                                        ', '\n...\n\n\n\n\n\n', '\r\n                                            28/02/202310:00\r\n                                        ', '\n...\n\n\n\n\n\n', '\r\n                                            02/02/202311:00\r\n                                        ', '\n...\n\n\n\n\n\n', '\r\n                                            01/02/202309:00\r\n                                        ', '\n...\n\n\n\n\n\n', '\r\n                                            30/01/202310:00\r\n                                        ', '\n...\n\n\n\n\n\n', '\r\n                                            25/01/202312:00\r\n                                        ', '\n...\n\n\n\n\n\n', '\r\n                                            25/01/202309:00\r\n                                        ', '\n...\n\n\n\n\n\n', '\r\n                                            24/01/202312:00\r\n                                        ', '\n...\n\n\n\n\n\n', '\r\n                                            24/01/202311:00\r\n                                        ', '\n...\n\n\n\n\n\n', '\r\n                                            24/01/202310:00\r\n                                        ', '\n...\n\n\n\n\n\n'
```

start cleaning:

```
datetime_clean = ' '.join(map(str,datetime_end_list))
datetime_clean2 = re.sub(r'^\s+', '', datetime_clean, flags=re.MULTILINE)
print(datetime_clean2)

17/04/202311:00
...
28/02/202310:00
...
02/02/202311:00
...
01/02/202309:00
...
30/01/202310:00
...
25/01/202312:00
...
25/01/202309:00
...
24/01/202312:00
...
24/01/202311:00
...
24/01/202310:00
...
```

Comment: Can you share an example of what you scrapped and also the code you have till this moment? Share your code, not screenshots please

Comment: I have done that, thank you

Comment: Add an example of html and your code, but not in screenshot please.

Comment: Okay, I have done the right thing  @JakyRuby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Without additional information about the scraped elements it is hard to give an exact answer, but based on your input this should point in a direction.*

Removing whitespaces or new line characters simply use the parameter [`strip=True`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) and to remove the `...` simply check for them and append only, if they are not in `df_text`:

```
for dt in datetime:
    df_text = dt.getText(strip=True)
    if '...' not in df_text:
        datetime_end_list.append(df_text)
```

*I would probably choose the selection of the elements differently, but this would require knowledge of the HTML structure.*

Comment: can this logic also be applied if the text are strings @HedgeHog

Comment: This would be predestined for [asking a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with exact this focus and examples of input strings and expected output - Strip a string and check if it contains something in general is possible, but depends on your needs.  Just drop the link to your new question we will have a look.

Comment: It worked for strings too, thank you for this